# Django NoReverseMatch at /provider/ 'providers' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

i'm learning django . having the above error when rendering the provider page , if i removed the the html code the page will load without error but with the below code it give the above error
thank in advance

the html:

```html
    <ul class="all-cat-list">

                        {% for category in category_list %}

                        <li><a href="{% url 'providers: provider_list_category' category.slug %}">{{category}}
                            <span class="num-of-ads">({{category.total_providers}})</span></a></li>
                        {% endfor%}

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <ol class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a active href="{% url 'providers :provider_list' %}> All Categories </a> </li>

                    {% if category %}

                        <li class="active">{{category}} </li>
                    {% endif%}
                </ol>
                <div class="ads-grid">
                    <div class="side-bar col-md-3">
                        <div class="search-hotel">
                        <h3 class="sear-head">Search</h3>
                        <form method="GET" action="{url 'providers : provider_list' %}">
                            <input type="text" value="Product name..."  name ="q" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Product name...';}" required="">
                            <input type="submit" value=" ">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

the Views:

```
    def providerlist(request,category_slug = None):
        category = None
        providerlist = Provider.objects.all()
        categorylist = Category.objects.annotate(total_providers=Count('provider'))

        if category_slug:
            category= get_object_or_404(Category, slug = category_slug)
            providerlist = Category.filter(category=category)
        search_query = request.GET.get('q')
        if search_query :
            providerlist = providerlist.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(description__icontains=search_query)|
                Q(category__category__name__icontains  = search_query)
        )

    template = 'provider/provider_list.html'

    context = {'provider_list': providerlist ,'category_list' : categorylist}

    return  render(request,template,context)


    def providerdetail(request,provider_slug):
        #print(provider_slug)
        providerdetail=get_object_or_404(Provider,slug=provider_slug)
        providerimage =  ProviderImages.objects.filter(provider = providerdetail)
        template ='provider/provider_detail.html'
        context = {'provider_detail': providerdetail, 'productimage' : providerimage}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'provider'
urlpatterns =[
path('', views.providerlist , name='provider_list'), path('<slug: category_slug>', views.providerlist , name='provider_list_category'),
path ('detail/<slug:provider_slug>',views.providerdetail, name='provider_detail')
    ]
```

Comment: 'providers: provider_list_category' Here and a couple of other places mentioning url should be provider: as your app name is provider.

Answer (score 1):

according to your app name in urls.py:

```
app_name = 'provider'
```

you have to change your all url template tags and remove s from end of the provider.it must be exactly same to your app_name.like below:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'provider: provider_list_category' category.slug %}">
```

also you can change your app name instead to:

```
app_name = 'providers'
```

Comment: thank you for the reply , have removed the s but still the error comming   NoReverseMatch at /provider/
'provider ' is not a registered namespace  ...

Comment: </div>
   <ol class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a active href="{% url 'provider:provider_list' %}> All Categories </a> </li>

    {% if category %}

     <li class="active">{{category}} </li>
    {% endif%}
   </ol>

Comment: <ul class="list">

        {%  for provider in provider_list  %}

         <a href="{%url 'provider : provider_detail' provider.slug %}">
          <li>
          <img src="{{provider.image.url}}" title="" alt="" />
          <section class="list-left">
          <h5 class="title">{{provider.name}}</h5>
          <span class="adprice"> Company </span>
          <p class="catpath">Mobile Phones » Brand</p>
          </section>
          <section class="list-right">
          <span class="date">Today,

Comment: 17:55</span>
          <span class="cityname">City name</span>
          </section>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </li>
         </a>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: can you put namespace in main urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Your html file should be `<a href="{% url 'provider: provider_list_category' category.slug %}">` and you make sure your urls.py in your project_name folder have

`urlpatterns = [ path('provider', include('provider.urls', namespace='provider')),`

Answer (score 0):

your app_name `provider` and you put name in html page `providers` you  change your `app_name='providers'` or change in html page like this

```
 <li class="active"><a active href="{% url 'provider:provider_list' %}"> All Categories </a> </li>
```

and main urls.py in put namespace where you include your app urls

```
urlpatterns = [path('provider', include('provider.urls', namespace='provider'))],
```

if you change your app_name='providers' then change namespace

```
urlpatterns = [path('provider', include('provider.urls', namespace='providers'))],
```